# Using a negated guard

Tags: javascript

Is there a nicer way to write the following?:

```
t = {
    name,
    color,
    teamId: !user?undefined:teamId,
    userId: user&&user.id
};
```

So if user is defined, then I wish to use userId, otherwise teamId.

```js
    const name = "Me";
    const color = "Red";
    let user;
    let teamId = 10;
    
    t = {
        name,
        color,
        teamId: !user?undefined:teamId,
        userId: user&&user.id
    };
    
    console.log(t)
    
    user = {id: 1};
    teamId = undefined;
    
    t = {
        name,
        color,
        teamId: !user?undefined:teamId,
        userId: user&&user.id
    };
    
    console.log(t)
```

Comment: Why not a simple `if/else`? And... is it even valid to return a dictionary with some keys unset? (name, color)

Comment: @Cyrille JS doesn't define a Dictionary as a built in object, that code is returning an object of type `any` instantiated on the spot right there.

Comment: My JS must be really, really rusty. Still I believe a simple if/else would be nicer to read :)

Comment: I'm not sure this does what you think it does in its present form: https://jsfiddle.net/knvfrz8d/ - do you want `false` or `undefined` when something is unset, because at present you have a mixture.

Comment: Why not just return both and let the consumer figure out which one to use?

Comment: I have updated how I defined teamId as it was setting to false instead of undefined. Now I have something which is even uglier...

Comment: @Baz now your `teamId` is *always* undefined. Run your example to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still a bit messy, but it only checks for the user once and is a bit more readable

```
return user ? { name, color, "userId": user.id } : { name, color, "teamId": teamId };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
{
    name,
    color,
    teamId: user ? undefined : teamId,
    userId: user ? user.id : undefined
};
```

Comment: Can you please change your answer so that you set to undefined instead of false. I have updated my question to reflect that this is what I'm after.